# Dataframe from list of list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I searched the website but nothing really matches.

I have an example data:

```
data_2 = [[{'url':'http://url1.com', 'traffic':810}], [{'url':'http://url2.com', 'traffic':811}]]
```

How to create a dataframe from that so that the output would look like this:

```
                             url traffic
0                 http://url1.com  810
1                 http://url2.com  811
```

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data_2 = [[{'url':'http://url1.com', 'traffic':810}], [{'url':'http://url2.com', 'traffic':811}]] 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_2, columns = ['url', 'traffic'])
print(df2)
```

but received a "ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten `data_2` then construct a DataFrame with it. One way to flatten it is to use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(data_2))
```

or you can construct a Series with `data_2`, `explode` it, convert the outcome to a list, then pass it to a DF constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(data_2).explode().tolist())
```

Output:

```
               url  traffic
0  http://url1.com      810
1  http://url2.com      811
```